# What exactly is a Dimension of a Matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, change-of-basis

As far as I know , Dimension is the number of elements in the basis of a matrix . Basis deals with linearly independent vectors. So for instance , if we have an nxn matrix and we reduce the matrix to it's row echelon form , the basis comprises of the linearly independent rows .  So as I understand it , dimension of a matrix ≤ order of the matrix. (Due to the fact that ,no. of linearly independent rows can never be more than the rows of the matrix itself)

Recently I came across this answer, **which proposed that a dimension of a 2x2 matrix can be 4.**

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/320688/708144

Can someone help me comprehend what a dimension actually is?

Comment: What is "the dimension of a matrix"?  In the post you cite, it is observed that $\operatorname{dim}(M_2(\mathbb{R}))  = 4$, which is not the dimension of a single matrix (whatever that means), but is the dimension of the space consisting of all of the $4\times 4$ matrices with real entries.

Comment: Oh , okay. I think I get it now. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 5):

A single matrix does not have any *dimension*, as this notion is reserved for vector spaces. In general a single matrix does not constitute a vector space.

The vector space of matrices of a fixed size $m\times n$ does have a dimension, namely $mn$, as it is generated under addition by the matrices with precisely one nonzero entry 1.

A matrix itself induces two vector spaces: its kernel and its image. The dimension of the image is determined by the number of linear independent columns of the matrix, which is called the *rank* of the matrix.

Comment: Say we have 3 vectors such as : (a,b,c) , (d,e,f) , (g,h,i). If I were to find the basis of the 'vector space' created by these vectors, I would put them in to a matrix (3x3) and reduce it into an echelon form and thereby we would get the rank and the dimension , is that right?

Comment: Yes, but you have to be careful. If you are only interested in the rank/dimension, then you may reduce the matrix as you like (doing column transformations or doing row transformations (I would refrain from mixing these)). It is a theorem that reducing rows and reducing columns yields the same rank number, hence the same dimension. If however you want to obtain a basis of your image as well, you have to reduce columns (supposed you put the vectors as columns of your matrix).

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much.

Comment: No worries :) Feel free to accept ;)

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as a basis for a matrix. A basis is a maximal linearly independent set in a vector space. For example the set
$$\{\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0},\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0},\pmatrix{0&0\\1&0},\pmatrix{0&0\\0&1}\}$$
in the space of $2\times 2$-matrices with real entries $\mathcal{M}_2(\mathbb{R})$, which is thus of dimension $4$. There is a [rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)) of a matrix, which is defined as the dimension of the space generated by  its columns .

Comment: Thank you , I still need to think about THIS particular subtopic , but I'll keep this in my mind . Again ,thank you so much!

Comment: All maximal linearly independent sets in a vectorspace have the same cardinality. This cardinality is the dimension of the vector space. All isomorphic vector spaces over a field $k$ can be characterized by this invariant, their dimension.